# What is the Probability that the Average Diameter of the Cupcakes that the students Got is **Less Than** $14 [cm]$.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, average, exponential-distribution

In a Party in the campus everyone that comes Gets a CupCake , Only **$5$** Students Came.

The Diameter of the cupcake is Exponential Random variable with $E(D) = 15 [cm]$.

What is the Probability that the Average Diameter of the Cupcakes that the students Got is **Less Than** $14 [cm]$.

**Final Answer**$: \fbox{0.3192}$

$\fbox{I think i need to use normal dist}$
$\fbox{i know that because when i use the Z table with Z = $-0.47$ I get the correct answer.}$

$1 - P(Z<0.47) = 1- 0.6808 = 0.3192$

I dont know how to approach  this question . First i thought using the **central limit therom** but i got wrong answer i knew that the number of students $n=5$ and it isn't $30\leq n$ thats why its wrong.

The only Thing i did was :

$D_{avg} = \frac{\sum_1^5 D_i}{5}$

$E(D_{avg}) = 15 [cm]$

$Var(D_{avg}) = 45 [cm^2]$

D~$\exp(\frac{1}{15})$

and i dont know how $D_{avg}$ distribute.

Comment: The formatting and random capitalizations in this question look bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of $5$ independent exponentially distributed random variables with mean $\ 15\ $ follows an [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) with shape parameter $5$ and rate parameter $\ \lambda=\frac{1}{15}\ $:
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^5D_i\le x\right)=1-e^{-\lambda x}\sum_{k=0}^4\frac {(\lambda x)^k}{k!}\ ,
$$
from which it follows that
\begin{align}
P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^5D_i}{5}\le 14\right)&=1-e^{-\frac{14}{3}}\sum_{k=0}^4\frac {\left(\frac{14}
{3}\right)^k}{k!}\\
&\approx 0.4992\ .
\end{align}
So, unless I'm misunderstanding the problem, either there's something missing from its statement, or the given answer of $\ 0.3192\ $ is incorrect.

Comment: How did you get the number $\frac{14}{3}$ in the Erlang ..

Comment: What if they solved it using normal distribution which makes the answer less accurate but under the circumstances of the course it’s good answer

Comment: We didn’t learn gamma distribution/ Erlang .

Comment: $\ \lambda=\frac{1}{15}\ $ and $\ x=5\cdot 14$, therefore $\ \lambda x = \frac{5\cdot14}{15}=\frac{14}{3}\ $.

Comment: But the normal approximation (with mean $\ 15\ $ and variance $\ 45\ $) gives $\ 0.4407\ $ by my calculation, not $\ 0.3192\ $.  Assuming the correct answer *is* $0.4992$, then the error in the normal approximation is about $\ 12\%\ $.  As you have realised, with only $5$ summands you can't expect the normal approximation to do much better than that.

Comment: Exactly that’s why I do agree your answer seems right but the one who wrote the question wrote $ 0.3192$